# Making POST request using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

I want to send email to my flask server using Ajax but its not working.
Below is my Code.
Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var email = "";
         $("#letter").on("click",function(){
             email = $("letterEmail").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/letters',
                data: JSON.stringify({Email: email}),
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'

            });
            $("#lettersForm").html("Sent");
            console.log(email.toString());
        });
        });
        </script>
```

Python View to handle this:

```
    @app.route("/letters", methods = ['POST'])
    def letters():
        email = request.json['Email']
        send_email("myemail@example.com","Email",str(email))
        return True
```

This is the html for the form

```
    <form id = "lettersForm">
                <div class="row uniform 50%">
                    <div class="8u 12u(mobilep)">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="letterEmail" placeholder="Email Address" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="4u 12u(mobilep)">
                        <input id = "letter" type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="fit" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

The problem is data is not sent from client side.
So I also get a `KeyError`on server side.
Please help.

Comment: "its not working" - what's not working? Are you getting console errors?

Comment: Are there any errors on the browser's console?

Comment: I get Email is undefined @Andy

Answer (score 1):

The `KeyError` is due to Flask not finding the key.  Note if stringify finds an empty email variable it will not include that key in the post automatically.

Also, do not use `request.json` directly, but instead use `request.get_json()`.

Comment: I also have other function in other html that makes post request using ajax and that works with <code>request.json</code>But not this

Comment: `request.json` works, but should not be used directly. See the docs http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/

Answer (score 0):

The client-side problem here is in this line:

```
email = $("letterEmail").val();
```

It will try to get any Element in the page with the tagName `letterEmail`, and I don't think you have it.

Probably, what you want to do here is to get it the Element by its ID:

```
email = $("#letterEmail").val();
```

Comment: I corrected it but its making a GET request @Buzinas and shows email in the url

Comment: @rajendrakadam Have you tried to send the object directly: `data: {Email: email},`, instead of stringifying it?

Comment: Yes I tried it now.Its again making a GET request @Buzinas

Comment: Try to use the `$.post` instead. E.g: `$.post('/letters', { Email: email });`

Comment: Should I not include the contentType?@Buzinas

Comment: @rajendrakadam The contentType you're using is the default one for `$.post`.

Comment: I again get a GET request and email shows up in the url @Buzinas

Comment: @rajendrakadam Is this `#letter` a `input[type=submit`? If yes, you must `preventDefault` the `click` event, because if you don't, the page will form will be posted. Paste in your question your HTML code, please.

Comment: html code is put in the question after editing.Please help Thanks in advance

Comment: @rajendrakadam change `$("#letter").on("click", function() { /*rest of your code*/ }` to `$("#lettersForm").on("submit",function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /*rest of your code*/ }`

Comment: I did @Buzinas but again it takes me to top of the page and shows email that I put in the url